# jQuery: Queuing fadeIn() and fadeOut() on different elements

Tags: jquery, callback, queue, fadein, fadeout

I've been working on this for several hours and I can't seem to figure out how to do this - I'm new to jQuery.

I want to fade out one div and then fade in another. I want to do this in sequence. I have tried putting fadeIn() in the callback of the fadeOut() function and queueing the two animations, but they still don't happen sequentially.

HTML:

```
<article id="foo">
    <div>one set of content, initially set to "display: block;"</div>
    <div id="bar">second set of content, initially set to "display: none;"</div>
    <div id="menu">the menu, which I don't want to fade</div>
</article>
```

Here are the two methods I've tried:

Using queue():

```
$("#foo div:not(#bar, #menu)").queue( function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
$(this).dequeue();
$("#foo div#bar").fadeIn('slow')    
});
```

Using the callback:

```
$("#foo div:not(#bar, #menu)").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("#foo div#bar").fadeIn('slow');   
});
```

This should be relatively simple as it's one I've seen on many websites - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your html look like? There might be different approaches to take that make it easier...

Comment: What happens when using the callback? I've personally had success with that approach. Check out: http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/ for one perhaps.

Comment: My HTML is:

<article id="foo">
<div> ... one set of content, initially set to "display: block;" </div>
<div id="bar"> ... second set of content, initially set to "display: none;" </div>
<div id="menu">... the menu, which I don't want to fade </div>
</article>

Comment: If you are copy-pasting the code, the part using callbacks has a error, 3rd line should be }); and not )};

Comment: the selectors for each block look weird. I'd do $("#foo") and $("#bar")

Answer (score 2):

Second method works fine: first fade out first `div` then in the callback fade in another.

Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHCR5/) and see for yourself.

If your code doesn't work I suggest you check your code because the one you've provided surely is **invalid**:

1. your end brackets are invalidly sequenced: `})` instead of your `)}`
2. your second selector (for fading in) should be `$("#foo div#bar")` otherwise nothing will fade in, because you don't have an element with `class="foo"` but rather `id="foo"`.

Putting all the obstacles aside this should work:

```
$("#foo div:first").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $("#foo #bar").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help. The code was not copy/pasted so those were just typos; they are not present in the code I'm using. As much as I appreciate that it should work, and that your example does work, it does not work on my end. I have this inside a click() function and that inside #(document).ready() - would either of those be changing the results?

Comment: @daysrunaway: Debug your code using Firebug. Set breakpoints on first sentences inside your functions (as well as anonymous ones that execute asynchronously) and see what's going on. Check your jQuery selectors that they actually have any elements etc. Debugging is your friend.

Comment: Hi Robert - I used Firebug but couldn't find anything. The jQuery selectors all have elements. I found an alternate fix by using .hide(0, callback) on div:not(#bar, #menu) and putting .fadeIn() in the callback function - it doesn't look as good, but it does the job. I have one more question though: now, whenever I execute the click() function before the fadeIn() function is finished (700 ms), there's a brief flash of both content <div>s showing. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Someting must be terribly wrong with your code. Have you tried my code exactly line by line? You're selectors are doing something wrong here. OR! You have certain style on your DIV elements that prevents this from working as expected (as in `display:none!important;` or something similar). The code I provided works. HSFiddle example proves it does as well. There is something definitely wrong with your code or css or both.

Comment: I can't figure it out - I've gone through it several times. Could it perhaps be a style in Richard Clark's HTML5 Reset, which I'm using for the website (http://html5reset.org/)?

Comment: @daysrunaway: Could be. The easiest way to check this is to also use Firebug. You probably have something so very obvious but since you've been looking at it for such a long time you can't see it. Get another pair of eyes for this part of your code and maybe someone else at work will spot it for you. But since you have some sort of flickering going on, I suppose you're having problems with your style. Turn it all off and step by step turn it back on and see when it breaks.

Comment: Even after I shut off all CSS styles, validated my HTML, and disable all JS files attached to the site except jQuery and my functions file, it continues to behave this way. It must be something related to the Javascript, which is here: http://kubikcreative.com/_/js/functions.js. I've gone through it all with Firebug and can't figure out what's going on... do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: @daysrunaway: Well then I suggest you put all relevant code that can reproduce this behaviour in JSFiddle and we'll check it out. But one more thing: Is this behaviour the same in all browsers or is it just Firefox? Did you check? If it's only FF then maybe you have some strange FF plugin that clashes with your site. Greasemonkey may be one such plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe retry your second method? It is working for me. I ran this in the dev console here on stackoverflow and it worked as expected, fading out first the tags for this question, then the stackoverflow logo:

```
$(".tagged").fadeOut('slow', function () { $("#hlogo").fadeOut('slow'); });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me - the functions definitely don't run sequentially as I can see the full content of each div for 600 ms ("slow").

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#foo").fadeOut('slow', function () {$("#bar").fadeIn('slow');});
```

Yeah, this isn't right for that HTML, see Rob's answer

Comment: This won't work because you'd make container invisible, hence child elements won't be visible afterwards no matter what.

Comment: @Rob I know, the HTML wasn't there qhen I wrote it, didn't know how it was set up.